# Failed to load resources?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, error-handling

I keep getting thrown this error Failed to load resource: data.json:1 net::ERR_FAILED, but not sure why.  the files are 'data.json', 'script.js', 'icd1ocm-codes-2024.html', and 'stylesheet.css'. Am I missing something within the html or the js? I have tried to use the fetch/getData() and that didn't work. I have put the files in a shared public folder. There are no servers only local computer files to work with. This is being used to creat a front-end database through html

```
**JSON**

    [
  {
    "code": "A00",
    "description": "Cholera"
  },
  {
    "code": "A01",
    "description": "Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers"
  },
  // more code-description pairs...
]
```

```js
// Retrieve the JSON data from the public folder
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      // Event listener for the search button
      document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchInput').value.toLowerCase();
        var filteredResults = data.filter(function(item) {
          return item.code.includes(searchTerm) || item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
        });

        displayResults(filteredResults);
      });
    }
  }
};
xhr.send();

// Function to display the search results
function displayResults(results) {
  var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
  resultsDiv.innerHTML = '';

  if (results.length === 0) {
    resultsDiv.textContent = 'No results found.';
  } else {
    results.forEach(function(result) {
      var resultItem = document.createElement('div');
      var codeSpan = document.createElement('span');
      codeSpan.textContent = result.code + ': ';
      var descriptionSpan = document.createElement('span');
      descriptionSpan.textContent = result.description;

      resultItem.appendChild(codeSpan);
      resultItem.appendChild(descriptionSpan);
      resultsDiv.appendChild(resultItem);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.content-wrapper{
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
p{
    text-align: justify;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.highlight{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: forestgreen;
}
h1, h2{
    font-weight: 400;
}

ul li{
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>ICD-10 Code/Description Search</title>
  <meta type="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>ICD-10 Code/Description Search</h1>
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Enter code or description">
  <button id="searchButton">Search</button>

  <div id="results"></div>

  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the other log lines as well as the network tab to see _why_ they fail.

Comment: These are the errors I am getting now.

icd10cm-codes-2024.html:16 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Public/CuraScript%20ICD-10-CM%20Front-end%20Database/data.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

     GET file:///C:/Users/Public/CuraScript%20ICD-10-CM%20Front-end%20Database/data.json net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: I put it on a local python -m http.server 8000, but it is still not working. Now I get these errors. 
script.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
    at script.js:13:28
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:12:36)

Comment: So the problem is solved. This is a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

This tells you you cannot use XHRs from the `file://` protocol. (Any such request would be categorized as CORS because `file://` URLs have a null origin.) Create a local webserver instead and use `http://`, then it will work.